# Deriving an expression for a confidence interval for σ^2 using the asymptotic distribution of √n(σ̂^2−σ^2)

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, confidence-interval, asymptotics, pivot

We have We have $X1,…,Xn i.i.d N(μ,σ^2) $where $μ$ is known and $σ^2$ isn't known. 
 $σ̂^2=(\frac{1}{n})∑(X_i−μ)^2$.

First of all what I did, I derived an equitailed 95% confidence interval for $σ^2$. But then if given that $σ̂^2$ is a sample mean, I found the asymptotic distribution of $√n(σ̂^2−σ^2)$. (Thank you for everyone who helped me on here to see where I had gone wrong!). I now want to find an alternative confidence interval for $σ^2$ using the asymptotic distribution of $√n(σ̂^2−σ^2)$. (Which was $N(0, 2σ^4)$.

I know that $(\frac{√n(σ̂^2−σ^2)}{(σ^2√2})$ $-> N(0,1)$, so my initial plan was to use this as a pivot. However thinking about it now, $σ^2$ is unknown so I think my pivot must be wrong. How would you go about deriving this confidence interval?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a homework question? In that case add the tag 'self-study'.

Comment: Why do you work with 'the asymptotic distribution', a normal distribution, instead of a chi-distribution? This might explain why you do not get the coverage that you expect.

Comment: You might find it easier to use the estimator $(1/n)\sum_i X_i^2 - \mu^2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\frac{\sqrt n(σ̂^2−σ^2)}{σ^2√2}) \sim N(0,1)$ ==> $\Pr(-Z <\frac{\sqrt n(σ̂^2−σ^2)}{σ^2√2} < Z) = \alpha$, where $Z$ is Z-score for $1-\frac 12\alpha$.

You can get a solution of $\sigma^2$ from $-Z <\frac{\sqrt n(σ̂^2−σ^2)}{σ^2√2}$, and another one from $\frac{\sqrt n(σ̂^2−σ^2)}{σ^2√2} < Z$.

From 
$$\frac{\sqrt n(σ̂^2−σ^2)}{σ^2√2} < Z$$
$${\sqrt n(σ̂^2−σ^2)} < Z{σ^2√2}$$
$${\sqrt nσ̂^2} < Z{σ^2√2}+\sqrt nσ^2$$
$${\sqrt nσ̂^2} < (√2Z+\sqrt n)σ^2$$
$$σ^2 > \frac {\sqrt nσ̂^2} {√2Z+\sqrt n}$$

Simulation using SAS: Sample size =1000, repeat 1000 times.

```
  data temp; do i = 1 to 1000; do j = 1 to 1000; x=rannor(665654); output; end; end; run;
  proc means noprint; var x; by i; output out= var var=var; run;
  data var; set var; l= var*sqrt(1000)/(sqrt(2)*(1.96) + sqrt(1000));
      u= var*sqrt(1000)/(sqrt(2)*(-1.96) + sqrt(1000)); cover = (l<=1 <=u);
  run;
  proc freq data=var; tables cover; run;

     cover    Frequency     Percent     
    ----------------------------------
       0          60        6.00      
       1         940       94.00      
    ----------------------------------
```

Set sample size to 10000 and repeat 10000 times (takes long time) The CI cover true value 1 9484 times

Comment: Not going to lie, that is what I did do but it didn't bring me the confidence interval I was expecting!

Comment: See added part in Answer. Could you finish other half?

Comment: I got that in my first attempt! I got the other half the same apart from the value of Z. Was thinking one side, the Z would be Z_α/2 and one Z_1-α/2. However, I don't think that this confidence interval is correct because when I go to code this, I have been told that I am expecting about 95% coverage and Im only getting 67% so I am confused. Sorry if that doesn't make sense!!

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this open-access paper](https://dx.doi.org/10.20982/tqmp.10.2.p107) in *The Quantitative Methods for Psychology* which lists many confidence intervals, including for standard deviations and variances.

(link corrected).

Comment: This link didn't work for me; I think the paper it's pointing to is here: http://www.tqmp.org/RegularArticles/vol02-1/p011/. (PDF link: https://www.tqmp.org/RegularArticles/vol02-1/p011/p011.pdf)